# Firebird table column order to save disk space

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a table with almost six-hundred columns that contains raw data from an outside source, each row being a single transaction.
How can I order the columns to make its on disk and in memory layout space efficient?

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/fb-internals.html I guess that having numeric and blob datatypes first, and chars/varchars last will help, but I'm not sure it will gain you a lot.

Comment: Looking at the link I provided, order is probably entirely irrelevant for the space usage, although you might save a few bytes if you have a lot of columns and group the nullable vs non-nullable columns, because that might provide some optimization for the RLE compression of the null bitmap: in other words: don't waste time on this.

Comment: I'll take anything I can get at this point.  I asked because I remembered a post from several years ago by Jim Starkey about column order, but can't find it.

Comment: Consider asking on the Firebird-support mailing list, maybe some one has a different idea, but as far as I can tell, order doesn't come into play.

Comment: Frankly, I am not sure Jim's experience is relevant any more for Firebird. He long departed for his post-Firebird architecture, and FB drifted on its own... Just shooting in the sky, but I expect his recent articles would be relevant for MySQL Vulkan more than for FB

Comment: Data normalization with triggers and update or insert.